# Is there still any size limitation of the image for UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

One of my clients asked me to make a composited image from two photos. They wanted to line selected images up and to create a new big image.

I used UIImageView for each image and set the images to it's image property. And then used CGContext to create a new lined up image and got a new UIImage.

When I used the photos taken by iPad, it worked fine and I could save the lined up new image to the Photo.

But when I tried it using two created big images, it crashed when tried to perform a segue with two images, and caused the iPad restart.

I got erros below.

```
2016-04-24 13:51:30.607 Kiss2-test[2664:3832804] XPC connection interrupted
2016-04-24 13:51:30.764 Kiss2-test[2664:3832514] Terminating since there is no system app.
```

I've found that these errors occur at segue.nextView. The nextView is shown from two different ViewControllers. The different is that one sends only one UIImage, while other sends two UIImage. And in my case, it happens in the second one.

Those two photos width and height are unknown until this nextView get them. So in

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {}
```

I wrote codes below.

```
firstImage = _argImage1;    // setting the first original UIImage to another UIImage
secondImage = _argImage2;   // setting the second original UIImage to another UIImage

// _placeHolder is a UIView wchich top is below navigation bar and bottom is above toolbar.
// This method is viewDidLayoutSubviews, so may be called several times.
// to avoid multiple constraints for the same view, remove them from _placeHolder
[_placeHolder removeConstraints:arrayLeftPlaceHolderConstraints];
[_placeHolder removeConstraints:arrayRightPlaceHolderConstraints];
[_placeHolder removeConstraints:aryCanvasViewConstraints];

// Canvas image will be added to _placeHolder to cover two images and
// let users draw images over photos.
expectedCanvasImageSize = CGSizeMake((firstImage.size.width + secondImage.size.width), (firstImage.size.height > secondImage.size.height)?firstImage.size.height:secondImage.size.height);

// Add two image's width to know the total width.
CGFloat summaryOfImageWidth = firstImage.size.width + secondImage.size.width;
// Get the ratio from each image.size.width devided by summaryOfImageWidth, so I can
// get the each UIImageView's widths.
CGFloat leftImageRatio = firstImage.size.width / summaryOfImageWidth;
CGFloat rightImageRatio = secondImage.size.width / summaryOfImageWidth;
// Get the both UIImageViews' width in _placeHokder.
leftImageWidth = _placeHolder.frame.size.width * leftImageRatio;
rightImageWidth = _placeHolder.frame.size.width * rightImageRatio;

// Prepare left side placeHolder.
if(!leftPlaceHolder) {
    leftPlaceHolder = [UIView new];
    [_placeHolder addSubview:leftPlaceHolder];
}

// Prepare right side placeHolder.
if(!rightPlaceHolder) {
    rightPlaceHolder = [UIView new];
    [_placeHolder addSubview:rightPlaceHolder];
}

// add constraints for both new placeholders.
// Left
// Set the left side to _placeHolder's left.
leftPlaceHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *leftPlaceHolderXConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                            multiplier:1
                              constant:0];

// Vertically center in _placeHolder
NSLayoutConstraint *leftPlaceHolderViewYConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

// set Width
NSLayoutConstraint *leftPlaceHolderWidthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:leftImageWidth];

// set Height
NSLayoutConstraint *leftPlaceHolderHeightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

// creating an array of constraints and add the array to _placeGolder constraints
arrayLeftPlaceHolderConstraints = @[leftPlaceHolderXConstraint, leftPlaceHolderViewYConstraint, leftPlaceHolderWidthConstraint, leftPlaceHolderHeightConstraint];
[_placeHolder addConstraints:arrayLeftPlaceHolderConstraints];

// right
// Set the right side to _placeHolder's right.
rightPlaceHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *rightPlaceHolderXConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                            multiplier:1
                              constant:0];

// Vertically center in _placeHolder
NSLayoutConstraint *rightPlaceHolderViewYConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

// set Width
NSLayoutConstraint *rightPlaceHolderWidthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:rightImageWidth];

// et Height
NSLayoutConstraint *rightPlaceHolderHeightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightPlaceHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

arrayRightPlaceHolderConstraints = @[rightPlaceHolderXConstraint, rightPlaceHolderViewYConstraint, rightPlaceHolderWidthConstraint, rightPlaceHolderHeightConstraint];
[_placeHolder addConstraints:arrayRightPlaceHolderConstraints];

// Creating CGRect for left placeHolder
leftRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, leftImageWidth,_placeHolder.frame.size.height);
// Creating CGRect for right placeHolder
rightRect = CGRectMake(leftImageWidth, 0, rightImageWidth, _placeHolder.frame.size.height);

// Get the image size to show using calcurateImageSize class.
// This initialization will prepare calcuration for size of firstImage to show in the leftRect.
imageSizeCalcurator = [[calcurateImageSize alloc]initWithBackGroundFrame:leftRect withImage:firstImage];
// Get the image size to show.
showingSize1 = [imageSizeCalcurator calcSingleImageMaximumSize];

imageSizeCalcurator = nil;
This initialization will prepare calcuration for size of secondImage to show in the rightRect.
imageSizeCalcurator = [[calcurateImageSize alloc]initWithBackGroundFrame:rightRect withImage:secondImage];
// Get the image size to show.
showingSize1 = [imageSizeCalcurator calcSingleImageMaximumSize];
showingSize2 = [imageSizeCalcurator calcSingleImageMaximumSize];

// Getting the expected size which will cover both two images shown.
CGFloat imageViewWidth = showingSize1.width + showingSize2.width;
CGFloat imageViewHeight = (showingSize1.height > showingSize2.height)?showingSize1.height:showingSize2.height;

// Creating new UIImageView in _placeHolder for two images.
if(!oneImageView) {
    oneImageView = [UIImageView new];
    [_placeHolder addSubview:oneImageView];
}
// Add constraints for new UIImageBiew
// Holizontally Center
oneImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *oneImageViewXConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:oneImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                            multiplier:1
                              constant:0];

// Vertically Center
NSLayoutConstraint *oneImageViewViewYConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:oneImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

// set Width
NSLayoutConstraint *oneImageViewWidthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:oneImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:imageViewWidth];

// set Height
NSLayoutConstraint *oneImageViewHeightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:oneImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:imageViewHeight];

NSArray *arrayOneImageConstraints = @[oneImageViewXConstraint, oneImageViewViewYConstraint, oneImageViewWidthConstraint, oneImageViewHeightConstraint];
[_placeHolder addConstraints:arrayOneImageConstraints];

// Image Sizes and Positions to draw in context
CGSize firstSize = firstImage.size;
CGSize secondSize = secondImage.size;
CGFloat firstYPos = (firstSize.height > secondSize.height)?0:(secondSize.height - firstSize.height) / 2;
CGFloat secondYPos = (secondSize.height > firstSize.height)?0:(firstSize.height - secondSize.height) / 2;

// CGRect to draw pictures.
CGRect firstRect = CGRectMake(0, firstYPos, firstSize.width, firstSize.height);
CGRect secondRect = CGRectMake(firstSize.width, secondYPos, secondSize.width, secondSize.height);

// Creating CGContext
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(expectedCanvasImageSize, NO, 0.0f);
// draw each image in the CGRect calcurated above.
[firstImage drawInRect:firstRect];
[secondImage drawInRect:secondRect];
// Gettomg composited UIImage Viedw
compositedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
// Ends CGContext image.
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

oneImageView.image = compositedImage;

// Creating a canvas Image Vew to let the user can draw abouve images.
if(!canvasImageView) {
    canvasImageView = [UIImageView new];
    canvasImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_placeHolder addSubview:canvasImageView];
    canvasImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    canvasImageView.image = nil;
}

if(drawImageBeforeSegue) {
    canvasImageView.image = drawImageBeforeSegue;
}


// Determine CanvasView's constraints
// Horizontally Center
NSLayoutConstraint *canvasViewCenterXConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:canvasImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

// Verticaly Center
NSLayoutConstraint *canvasViewCenterYConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:canvasImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:_placeHolder
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

// set the Width
NSLayoutConstraint *canvasViewCenterWidthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:canvasImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:imageViewWidth];

// set the Height
NSLayoutConstraint *canvasViewCenterHeightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:canvasImageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:imageViewHeight];

aryCanvasViewConstraints = @[canvasViewCenterXConstraint, canvasViewCenterYConstraint, canvasViewCenterWidthConstraint, canvasViewCenterHeightConstraint];
[_placeHolder addConstraints:aryCanvasViewConstraints];
```

As the code above is written in viewDidLayoutSubviews, so First of all, I remove constraints.

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash and post relevant code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I'll update the question as soon as possible.

Comment: You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size.

Comment: I've seen many people says so. And I've read the newest UIImage class reference, but I couldn't find any size limitation issues.
Would you please let me know how can I find that limitation in a document? Then I can show that to my client.

And I wonder that if UIImage only accepts 1024 x 1024 at its max size, How does Photo.app show the image? I don't use optimization for the device, so I believe photos on my devices are original size.

Comment: You are only limited by available memory.  As you have no way of knowing how much that will be for any run on any device, you should keep in mind that a phone is not a laptop or desktop, the latter two of which have swap space and usually way more RAM installed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to explain that to my client. Then we're going to find another way. Thank you again!